# Post-increment does not work with a dereferenced pointer

Tags: c++

I have code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main()
{
    int b = 5;
    int * a = &b;
    *a++;
    std::cout << *a;
}
```

Why pre-incremental works well, but post not working?

Comment: The `*a++;` is as if you did `*a; ++a;`.

Comment: [C++ operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) - post-increment has higher precedence than dereference, so it's `*(a++);`

Comment: oh ok, i got it

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Using pre-incrementation, there is no ambiguity `++*a` increment the pointed, `*++a` increment the pointer. But with post-incrementation parentheses may be needed: `(*a)++`the pointed is incremented, `*a++` or `*(a++)` the pointer is incremented.

Comment: `std::cout << *a;` is UB because a no longer points to b. Could point to anything.